# How to add all phone contacts in Sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, contacts, android-cursor

In my Android app,i am retreiving phone contacts through cursor. Then i want to add all these contacts in database as follows:

```
    public class SettingsActivity extends Activity  {
    ToggleButton tb_hide;
    ToggleButton tb_unhide;
    TextView tv_add_contacts;
    TextView tv_restore_contacts;
    DbManager manager;
    Context context;
    String[] privateContacts;
    Uri queryUri;
    String selectIds = "";
    String ContactId[];
    String ContactNames[];
    String ContactNumbers[];
    public static String[] wholContactData;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
        try{
            context = this;
            findView();
            queryUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

            //String selected_data = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " IS NOT NULL";
            Cursor Cursor = getContentResolver().query
                    (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
            privateContacts=showEvents(Cursor);
            wholContactData=new String[privateContacts.length];
            tv_add_contacts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    addcontacts();
                }
            });
            tv_restore_contacts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    for(int i=0;i<privateContacts.length;i++){
                        selectIds = selectIds + " | " + privateContacts[i];
                        wholContactData[i]=privateContacts[i];
                    }
                    try{
                        addAllContacts(wholContactData);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        Log.e("ERROR in adding all contacts", ex.toString());
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+selectIds, 3000).show();

                }});
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e("Add all contacts ERROR", ex.toString());
        }
    }


    private void addAllContacts(final String[] selectedItems) {
        try{

                manager.open();
                manager.Insert_phone_contact(selectedItems);
                manager.close();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("ERROR", ex.toString());
        }
    }




    protected String[] showEvents(Cursor cursor) {
        ContactId= new String[cursor.getCount()];
        ContactNames = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        ContactNumbers = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        int i=0;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            ContactId[i] = i+"";
            ContactNames[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            ContactNumbers[i] = Util.getContactNumber(ContactNames[i], context);
            i++;

        }

        return ContactNames;
    }


    private void findView() {
        TextView tv_hide = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_hide);
        TextView tv_hide_desc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_hide_desc);

        tv_add_contacts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_add_contacts);
        TextView tv_add_contacts_desc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_add_contacts_desc);
        tv_restore_contacts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Tv_restore_contacts);
        TextView tv_restore_contacts_desc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_restore_contacts_desc);

        tb_hide = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tb_hide);
        tb_hide.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                HideUnhideIcon();
            }});


    }
    private void HideUnhideIcon() {
        if(tb_hide.isChecked()){
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            ComponentName com_name = new ComponentName("com.android.discrete.main",
                    "com.android.discrete.main.SplashScreen");
            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(com_name, 
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your app is hidden now, Dial provided security code  to get into discrete app.", 3000).show();
        }
        else if(tb_hide.isChecked()==false){
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            ComponentName com_name = new ComponentName("com.android.discrete.main",
                    "com.android.discrete.main.SplashScreen");
            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(com_name, 
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED
                    ,
                    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP );

        }


    }

    private void addcontacts() {
        final ProgressDialog myPd_ring=ProgressDialog.show(this, "Phone Contacts", "Loading please wait..", true);
        myPd_ring.setCancelable(true);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {  
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try
                {
                    movetoPrivateContacts();
                }catch(Exception e){}
                myPd_ring.dismiss();
            }

        }).start();                                          
    }
    private void moveToLogActivity() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, LogActivity.class); 
        startActivity(i);
        finish();

    }


    private void movetoPrivateContacts() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,privateContacts.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

Database code is as follows:

```
public void Insert_phone_contact(String [] contact){
    try{

        SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        for(int i=0;i<contact.length;i++){
           // put all values in  ContentValues
            if (contact[i] !=null){
            cv.put(CONTACT_NAME, ""+contact[i]);

            DB.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, cv); 
            }// insert in db
        }

        DB.close();  // call close
        }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e("Error in phone contact insertion", ex.toString());
    }

}
```

i want to add all contacts to database when i click "tv_restore_contacts" .But i am getting NullPointerException. I don't know where i am wrong?
logcat Error stack is `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Comment: post your logcat stack trace

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Copy error stack from logcat and post in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to grab the contacts & return them to a list datatype to save them whole list in a db or open a DB connection inside the method and do sql insert statements on each contact object you wish to store. N/B The Contacts API is deprecated be sure to use ContactsContract Api.

```
Private void getDetails(){
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
    String[] projection    = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER };
    Cursor names = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int indexName = names.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int indexNumber = names.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
    names.moveToFirst();
    do {
       String name   = names.getString(indexName);
       Log.e("Name new:", name);
       String number = names.getString(indexNumber);
       Log.e("Number new:","::"+number);
    } while (names.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: In your code, why even bother querying the contacts.content_uri if you are not using it at all? Your code won't work, you need to query contacts, then use the contactid to get the phone entries. Displayname comes from contacts, number comes from phone